# Private Block chain App

Tags: mining-theory

I would love to use monero to "power" my private block chain app. 
Would this be overkill?  Would ethereum be secure "enough"?

Comment: Can you be more specific? It is hard to understand exactly what you are attempting to do

Comment: Of course, I would love to be able to create my own block chain using monero as the encryption process.  I can see using block chain for school transcripts. The records would need to be very secure. Ethereum can be used to create a private block chain. Is it possible to do the same with monero?  Would ethereum be secure enough or should I use monero?

Comment: Can you edit your original question based on this comment? You are likely were downvoted because you original question remains unclear. Not everyone reads the comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either Monero or Ethereum would be overkill. Saving non-financial data on Monero would be expensive. What you're looking for is an encrypted database.

Monero is private in the sense that users are anonymous. Private blockchains in the sense that they're run by one entity are simply inefficient databases. The security and immutability of a blockchain depends on having multiple users run nodes and having multiple miners create blocks.

In the case of school transcripts, the school can be trusted to keep its own records and a trustless solution will not be necessary.